# Derivative of $f(x) = \frac{\cos{(x^2 - 1)}}{2x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of the function $$f(x) = \frac{\cos{(x^2 - 1)}}{2x}$$

This is my step-by-step solution: $$f'(x) = \frac{-\sin{(x^2 - 1)}2x - 2\cos{(x^2 -1)}}{4x^2} = \frac{2x\sin{(1 - x^2)} - 2\cos{(1 - x^2)}}{4x^2} = \frac{x\sin{(1 - x^2)} - \cos{(1 - x^2)}}{2x^2} = \frac{\sin{(1 - x^2)}}{2x} - \frac{\cos{(1-x^2)}}{2x^2}$$

and this is the output of WolphramAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+cos(x^2+-+1)%2F(2x)

Where is the mistakes?

Comment: Early error, beginning of first line:  the derivative of $\cos(x^2-1)$ should be $-2x\sin(x^2-1)$, Chain Rule. Multiply that by $2x$.

Comment: You're neglecting to use the chain rule where you need it.

Comment: @abiessu: the $2x$ is from the quotient rule in this case; if the chain rule was applied correctly, it would be shown as $-\sin(x^2-1)4x^2$.

Comment: @abiessu: Then it should be $2x$ times that. It is more likely that Chain Rule was forgotten than part of the Quotient Rule was forgotten.

Comment: I just spent 10 minutes thinking "I've already multiplied $sin(x^2 - 1)$ by $2x$, why are they telling me to multiply it again?"... then I noticed that the derivative of the $x^2 - 1$ is equals to the denominator... but this is definitely not a good reason to don't multiply by $2x$ again :D thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first step, when you take the derivative of $\cos(x^2 - 1)$ in the quotient rule calculation, you're getting $-\sin(x^2-1)$, when you should be getting $-2x\sin(x^2 - 1)$ by the chain rule. This is then multiplied by the $2x$ from the denominator, giving $-4x^2\sin(x^2 - 1)$.

This is the only error--you'll notice that the difference between your solution and WolframAlpha's is the factor of $2x$ on the $\sin$ term.

Answer (score 3):

You need the chain rule:
$$
\frac d {dx} \cos(x^2-1) = -\sin (x^2-1)\cdot\frac d{dx}(x^2-1)=\cdots.
$$

Comment: @abiessu : I think you're mistaken.   The $2x$ that appear there was the denominator.  I.e. the quotient rule says $\displaystyle\frac d{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$.  The $2x$ in the first term in the numerator is $g(x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You are right, I mentally made the same mistake except I used the chain rule and dropped the $g(x)$...

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating $\cos(x^2-1)$ gives you $-2x\sin(x^2-1)$, using the Chain Rule

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: i am just pointing out the obvious error

Comment: @G.Sassatelli:... Unless, of course, the error is in the incorrect application of the Quotient Rule...

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{\cos{(x^2 - 1)}}{2x}\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}\left(\frac{\cos{(x^2 - 1)}}{2x}\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\left(\frac{\cos{(x^2 - 1)}}{x}\right)\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x\frac{df(x)}{x}(\cos(1-x^2))-\cos(1-x^2)\frac{df(x)}{dx}x}{x^2}\right)=$$
$$\frac{x\frac{df(x)}{x}(\cos(1-x^2))-1\cos(1-x^2)}{2x^2}=$$
$$\frac{-\cos(1-x^2)+2x(x\sin(1-x^2))}{2x^2}=$$
$$\frac{-\cos(1-x^2)+x^2\sin(1-x^2)}{2x^2}$$